# Unique Paths II, dynamic programming problem, O(n^2) time, O(n^2) space

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is based on this [leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-paths-ii/).  I get the correct answer, but I know it could be much, much cleaner.  I also know there is supposed to be an O(n) space solution, but I'm not sure how to implement cleanly.

It is a dynamic programming problem, I tried to add some helpful code comments, I know it's pretty messy so thank you for your review.

```py
class Solution:
    def uniquePathsWithObstacles(self, obstacleGrid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
        #initialize memoization array
        memo = [[-1 for i in range(len(obstacleGrid[0]))] for j in range(len(obstacleGrid))]


        #add known values before any calculation (last row and last column)
        memo[len(memo)-1][len(memo[0])-1] = 1
        for i in range(len(memo[0])-2,-1,-1):
            if obstacleGrid[len(memo)-1][i] != 1:
                memo[len(memo)-1][i] = memo[len(memo)-1][i+1]
            else:
                memo[len(memo)-1][i] = 0 
        
        for j in range(len(memo)-2,-1,-1):
            if obstacleGrid[j][len(memo[0])-1] != 1:
                memo[j][len(memo[0])-1] = memo[j+1][len(memo[0])-1]
            else:
                memo[j][len(memo[0])-1] = 0
        
        if obstacleGrid[len(memo)-1][len(memo[0])-1] == 1:
            return 0 
        
        #does calculations
        def helper(row,col):
            nonlocal memo
            if obstacleGrid[row][col] == 1:
                return 0 
            if memo[row][col] == -1:
                memo[row][col] = helper(row+1,col) + helper(row,col+1)
            return memo[row][col]
        
        return helper(0,0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Nice solution, few suggestions:

- **Duplicated code**: the functions `len(memo)` and `len(memo[0])` are called several times. When working with a matrix is common to call `m` the number of rows (`len(memo)`) and `n` the number of columns (`len(memo[0])`). This can help to reduce the duplicated code. As @Manuel mentioned in the comments, `m` and `n` are also defined in the problem description.
- **Last element of a list**: instead of `memo[len(memo)-1]` you can use `memo[-1]`.
- **Input validation**: this input validation:

  ```
  if obstacleGrid[len(memo)-1][len(memo[0])-1] == 1:
      return 0
  ```

  is done too late in the code, after the `memo` matrix is fully built. Better to move it up at the beginning of the function. BTW, with the previous suggestion, it can be shortened to:

  ```
  if obstacleGrid[-1][-1] == 1:
      return 0
  ```
- **Naming**: the row is called `row` in the helper function and `j` in the rest of the code. Same for the column. Use the same name to be consistent.
- **Throwaway variables**: in the initialization of memo:

  ```
  memo = [[-1 for i in range(len(obstacleGrid[0]))] for j in range(len(obstacleGrid))]
  ```

  the variables `i` and `j` are not used. They can be replaced with `_`.
- **Type hints**: the `helper` function is missing the type hints.
- **LRU cache**: there is a handy annotation that does the memoization automatically, [@lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache). Or the unbounded `@cache` in Python 3.9.

An example using `@lru_cache`:

```py
def uniquePathsWithObstacles(self, obstacleGrid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
    m = len(obstacleGrid)
    n = len(obstacleGrid[0])

    if obstacleGrid[-1][-1] == 1:
        return 0

    @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def helper(row: int, col: int) -> int:
        if row == m - 1 and col == n - 1:
            return 1
        if row < m and col < n:
            if obstacleGrid[row][col] == 1:
                return 0
            return helper(row + 1, col) + helper(row, col + 1)
        return 0

    return helper(0, 0)
```

For dynamic programming solutions, you can have a look at the "Solution" [section](https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-paths-ii/solution/) or "Discussion" [section](https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-paths-ii/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=hot&query=&tag=python&tag=dynamic-programming) using tags `python` and `dynamic programming`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for I always struggle with these 2-D DP problems, this will make it a lot easier, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For O(n) space, I think you need to switch from your top-down DP to bottom-up DP. That lets you control the evaluation order so you can for example go row by row, and store only the numbers of paths for the current row.

To simplify things, start with an imaginary row *above* the grid and say you have *one* path right above the real start cell and *zero* paths above the rest. Then just update these numbers by going through the grid's rows.

```
def uniquePathsWithObstacles(self, obstacleGrid: List[List[int]]) -> int:
    paths = [1] + [0] * (len(obstacleGrid[0]) - 1)
    for row in obstacleGrid:
        for j, obstacle in enumerate(row):
            if j:
                paths[j] += paths[j - 1]
            if obstacle:
                paths[j] = 0
    return paths[-1]
```

Btw, you're *not* O(n^2) but O(mn).

Comment: Just to test my understanding would the first row then be set to all 1's in the first iteration of the row loop?

Comment: @JosephGutstadt Only if there are no obstacles. If there are obstacles, it would be ones until the first obstacle, and zeros starting at the first obstacle. That's the advantage of that imaginary extra row: I don't have to duplicate the logic of handling obstacles, like you do in your initialization.

Comment: Ahhh, very nice, that was my next question, Thank you